# Powershell new-pssession works on each -hostname individually, but access denied when trying both at once

Tags: powershell, ssh

I have tested

```
New-PSSession -HostName server01 -UserName myname
```

and

```
New-PSSession -HostName server02 -UserName myname
```

and both commands prompt for the password and then connect to each server without issue.
However, when I attempt

```
New-PSSession -HostName server01,server02 -UserName myname
```

the prompt returned is

```
Enter server01's password: Enter server02's password:
```

and although it is the same for both machines, I am receiving an access denied error every time I enter the password.

I have tried entering the password twice, comma separated, and colon separated. I am trying to follow examples given in a book that uses the same format for the command - multiple hostnames, and the username parameter. The prompt for the first server's password appears, and before I can begin typing, the second server password prompt appears on the same line. I expected one password prompt, since both machines use the same username/password credentials. I am not attempting a double hop.

Comment: thank you for helping me format my question properly.

Comment: See Blue link at following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/new-pssession?view=powershell-7.3#-authentication

Comment: does it work if you try with `New-PSSession -HostName server01,server02 -Credential (Get-Credential)` ? Also if this is truly SSH, it might be a good idea to follow the guidance on [Example 14](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/new-pssession?view=powershell-7.3#example-14-create-multiple-sessions-using-ssh) using the `-SSHConnection` parameter using key based auth